# Is there a way to continue to view a popup modal after a user logs in?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015

I have code where a user needs to login to view our "pricing popup". After the user logs in, I want the pricing popup to show again as if the login never happened. I don't want the user to have to have re-click to open the popup again if it was already open before logging in.

I can't use PHP because the web app we are using can't use it. I really need this answer to be JavaScript. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and I believe the framework is MVC.

I've tried moving things around to see if I maybe have the wrong syntax.
I've also tried location.reload but I get the same problem where the modal doesn't show up after the refresh.

This code requires the user to login to view the popup. Problem is after logging in the popup disappears.

```
function CheckEmail(e) {
var data = $('#signInForm').serializeArray();
var controller = (typeof CURRENT_CONTROLLER != undefined) ? CURRENT_CONTROLLER : "Home";
ShowHideLoader(true);
if (isValidEmail(data[1]["value"])) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/../Account/FindByNameOrEmailAsync',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "usernameOrEmail": data[1]["value"] }),
        context: this,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            ShowHideLoader(false);
            //alert(data);
            if (data.status) {
                $("#emailCheck").hide();
                $("#enterPassword").fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $('#enterPassword').fadeIn(500);
                });
            } else {
                //$.get("Account/RegisterRedirect", { Email: $("#signin_email").val() });
                if (controller == "Business") {
                    $("#login-modal").modal("hide");
                    $("#signup-modal").modal('show');
                    SignupEmail.SetValue($("#signin_email").val());
                } else
                    window.location = data.returnUrl;
            }

            ShowHideLoader(false);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error! Src: /Account/FindByNameOrEmailAsync");
            ShowHideLoader(false);
        }
    });
} else {
    $("#wrongEmail").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#wrongEmail').fadeIn(500);
    });

    $("#authInfo").hide();
    ShowHideLoader(false);
}
```

}

```
function ShowHideLoader(visible) {
if (visible)
    $(".signin-preloader").css("visibility", "visible");
else
    $(".signin-preloader").css("visibility","hidden");
```

}

```
function ShowHideSignUpLoader(visible) {
if (visible)
    $(".signup-preloader").css("visibility", "visible");
else
    $(".signup-preloader").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

}

```
function ValidateForm(data) {
if (data.res) {
    $("#SignInMenuItem").hide();
    $('#login-modal').modal("toggle");

    if (typeof HeaderMenu != "undefined")
        HeaderMenu.GetItemByName("SignInMenuItem").SetVisible(false);

    //$('#mainHeaderPanel').load('/Base/MainHeaderPanel?controller=' + data.controller);

    //if (data.controller == "Business")
    {
        //mainHeaderPanel.PerformCallback();
        //LoadSearchHistory();
        //$("#header-menu").append("<div class=\"user-info-header\"><div class=\"header-userName\">Welcome, <a data-toggle=\"dropdown\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\">" + data.userName + " <b class=\"caret\"></b></a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu\"><li class=\"divider\"></li><li class=\"nav-header\">User actions</li><li><a onclick=\"LoadPurchasedItemsCurrentUser()\">My purchased items</a></li><li><a href=\"/Account/Logoff\">Logout</a></li></ul></div><div class=\"btn-logoff header-log-off\"><a href=\"/Account/Logoff\">Logout</a></div></div>");
        //$("#HeaderMenu_DXI5_").hide();
    }
    // else

    if (showPopup == 'showPricing') {
        $("#pricingPopup").modal("show");

    }

    window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;


}
else {
    $("#passInfo").hide();
    $("#wrongPass").fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#wrongPass').fadeIn(500);
    });
}
```

}

//This portion checks to see if the user is signed in. If not, they are required to sign in to view the popup.

```
var showPopup;

var showModalForSignIn = function (seePricing) {
$("#login-modal").modal("show");
$("#authInfo").hide();
$("#needSigninMessage").show();

showPopup = seePricing;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I only see `$("#pricingPopup")` beging used once in your code.
Without the HTML I can't see what is happening but it could be that you have another class or ID on the pricing popup that conflicts with another popup.
For these kind of questions it's best to create a codepen to illustrate the problem.

Is the pricing popup still present in the DOM after logging in or is the template removed from the DOM?

If it is still present you could just show it again after logging in with .show().
If it is not present anymore you should take a look at what removes it from the DOM.

Comment: The pricingPopup is a link in the navigation that the user must click on to view. It's in my topMenu.xml   <item Text="Pricing">
    <item Text="Lead Lists" NavigateUrl="" Name="pricingPopup" />